# Do our dreams to happen as few?

Tags: quran, tafseer, dream

We know that our dreams can happen in future. I read Qu'ran.

> *"when Allah showed them to you in your dream as few; and if He had shown them to you as many, you [believers] would have lost courage and would have disputed in the matter [of whether to fight], but Allah saved [you from that]. Indeed, He is Knowing of that within the breasts. [8:43]"*

Does it mean our few dreams can happen only? If we had many dreams, does it mean they will not happen?

I am waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is an incorrect reading of the ayah.

"When Allah showed them to you in your dream as few", that's referring to the Prophet's dream before the [Battle of Badr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Badr), where the *enemy* was shown "as few" so as not to discourage him. It has nothing to do with the *number* of dreams he — or the believers — had received or would receive.